# What are these insects on my Arabian Jasmine plant & how can I eradicate them?

Tags: identification, pest-control, pests, insects, pesticide

I have found these white moths (very small, winged, can fly) below the leaves of my Arabian jasmine plant, and the plant has stopped flowering and is in a poor state. There are surprisingly some white scaly patches too on the leaves, though I am not sure if these are related with the white moth. They look more like fungi to me though I might be wrong. I have tried using insecticides but they don't seem to be working, and the moths and the scales keep coming back. Can anyone please help me identify the insect/fungus and suggest a remedy?

[image: white fly and scales]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happened to my jasmine plant recently and it stopped flowering for a couple of months. I sprayed some alcohol on the underside of the leaves for a few days straight, trim away damaged leaves and fertilized the soil. She is flowering again almost immediately after that.

Answer (score 5):

As the renowned Stephie has pointed out in the comment this is Whitefly which is a very common pest.  The scales are discarded pupae cases from the larvae.

The key in pest control is to:

- remove other sources of whitefly which can reinfect the plant. Are other plants infected?  Remove them and isolate this plant from healthy ones
- spray with 5ml dish soap to one liter of water, or, wipe down with a cloth soaked in the solution
- repeat at five to seven day intervals so you catch the eggs as they hatch
- three applications or more are likely to be needed

Comment: "renowned" - tsk! I simply didn't have time for an answer (or a duplicate search). But thanks for stepping up - have an upvote! ^_^

Comment: Does wipedown really work on a jasmine? Otherwise that answer is what I would do... @Stephie you are "The Renowned Stephie" :D

Comment: @J.Musser clarified you have to wipe w soap and water.  Tedious and time consuming but effective

Comment: @kevinsky Yes, naturally. I just meant using a small sprayer seems like it would give much better coverage, as not all plants are apt for a wipedown.

Comment: @J.Musser a wipedown will crush the eggs that will otherwise be unharmed by soap and water.  It's only the pyrethrins and perhaps neem oil that have a residual activity that will control the next hatching without more attention.  Some people don't have sprayers and have lots of time.  That method is for them.